# ssh remembers my key

Tags: ssh

I have a server in the web and I'm very concerned about security. I'm using custom private key

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email@example.com"
```

and I'm using it only for this server. I've added this key to `authorized_keys` on the server.

I'm using this ssh command to login:

```
ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -i key_file
```

But, after successful login, I'm able to login to my server using this command:

```
ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

without setting `-i key_file`. Why is that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you are adding `-i PATH` to your key_file which is being stored in default location. So basically it doesn't matter if you provide -i argument or not, since ssh will search for the key file in a default location anyways.

> -i identity_file
>
> Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public key
>   authentication is read.  The default is `~/.ssh/identity` for protocol
>   version 1, and `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa`
>   for protocol version 2.  Identity files may also be specified on a
>   per-host basis in the configuration file.  It is possible to have
>   multiple -i options (and multiple identities specified in
>   configuration files). ssh will also try to load certificate information from the filename obtained by appending `-cert.pub` to identity filenames.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh

Comment: please cite your sources when you copy/paste

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you are using *ssh multiplexing*. This is activated by the `ssh` option `ControlMaster auto` given in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or `~.ssh/config` or at the commandline.

This feature allows the sharing of one underlying socket for multiple logical connections. Authentication only occurs once.

If you start ssh with  the `-v` switch some information about `mux` for multiplexing can be seen.

```
blafasel@talbot:~$ ssh -v some.whe.re
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/blafasel/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/blafasel/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 4
blafasel@some:~$
```